# WKExtensionsDelegateClassName is Invalid in info.plist

Tags: watchkit

So I am banging my head, I realized my stand along Watch App had a STUPID long name of "App Name - WatchKit App" so I went into my Target and changed the Display Name to "App Name" removing WatchKit App. Well now my app won't validate when uploading to the Appstore. I get the message - Invalid Info.plist key. The key `WKExtensionDelegateClassName in bundle App Name.app/Watch/App Name WatchKit App.app is invalid.`
My Info.plist has the value of

```
<key>WKExtensionDelegateClassName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtensionDelegate</string>
```

I have confirmed that I have  `@WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var delegate` in my @main for the SwiftUI App. And when I print a few values in my app launch I get the following confirmations:

```
Super Init - ExtensionDelegate
Contentview
applicationDidFinishLaunching for watchOS
Super Init - ExtensionDelegate
Optional(Wasted_Time_Watch_Extension.MeetingSetup)
Optional(Wasted_Time_Watch_Extension.MeetingStatistics)
Optional(Wasted_Time_Watch_Extension.Meeting)
applicationDidBecomeActive for watchOS
update complication
```

I create three classes at launch and print this in the log with print(ExtensionDelegate.shared.Setup as Any) , etc. The other lines are just confirming where I am at app startup.
This is a WatchOS8 application and I am running Xcode version Version 13.1 (13A1030d).

Update - Here's the entry in my plist

```
    <key>WKExtensionDelegateClassName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtensionDelegate</string>
    <key>WKWatchOnly</key>
```

And my App code

```
import SwiftUI
#if os(watchOS)
import ClockKit
#endif

struct DelegateKey: EnvironmentKey {
    typealias Value = ExtensionDelegate
    static let defaultValue: ExtensionDelegate = ExtensionDelegate()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var extensionDelegate: DelegateKey.Value {
        get {
            return self[DelegateKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[DelegateKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}

@main
struct WastedTimeWatchApp: App {
    @WKExtensionDelegateAdaptor(ExtensionDelegate.self) var delegate

    let prefs: UserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: suiteName)!

    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
                    .environment(\.extensionDelegate, delegate)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, ObservableObject {

    @Environment(\.extensionDelegate) static var shared

    // variables removed to simplify posting

    override init() {
        print("Super Init - ExtensionDelegate")
        super.init()
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        print("applicationDidFinishLaunching for watchOS")
        ExtensionDelegate.shared.meetingSetup = MeetingSetup()
        print(ExtensionDelegate.shared.meetingSetup as Any)
        ExtensionDelegate.shared.meetingStatistics = MeetingStatistics()
        print(ExtensionDelegate.shared.meetingStatistics as Any)
        ExtensionDelegate.shared.meeting = Meeting()
        print(ExtensionDelegate.shared.meeting as Any)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        print("applicationDidBecomeActive for watchOS")
        print("update complication")
        let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
        for complication in server.activeComplications ?? [] {
            server.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
        }
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeInactive() {
        print("update complication")
        let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
        for complication in server.activeComplications ?? [] {
            server.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
        }
        print("applicationDidBecomeInactive for watchOS")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out... I had duplicated the plist entry in both the WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension plist file. Removed it from the list WatchKit Extension plist and all is working fine.